# How to create a textblock and bind a text resource to it in behind code?

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml

The following XAML-Code works without problem:

```
<TextBlock Text="{DynamicResource myresourceitem}"/>
```

Behind code changes of 'myresourceitem' change the text of the textblock and everything is fine.

However, when I try to create this textblock in behind code the textblock shows the text of 'myresourceitem', but is not updated after changes of 'myresourceitem':

```
Dim tb As New TextBlock   
......
......
Dim bnd As New Binding
bnd.Source = Application.Current.FindResource("myresourceitem")
tb.SetBinding(TextBlock.TextProperty, bnd)
```

'myresourceitem' is a resource of Application.Current.Resources.
What do I do wrong? Why is this binding not working properly?
Must I maybe set bnd.Path to some value?

Comment: Is `myresourceitem` in App.xaml?

Comment: In the loaded event of mainwindow i dynamically create a resourcedicctionary 'dict' which I then dynamically add with Application.Current.Resources = dict.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your XAML and your code do *not* do the same thing at all. Your XAML is setting the `TextBlock.Text` property to a `DynamicResource` named `myresourceitem`, *not* a `Binding`. Your code on the other hand seems to be trying to create a `Binding` using the `myresourceitem` Resource as the `Binding Source`.

However, this should work both ways. Therefore, I can only assume that you are not accessing your resource correctly... do you receive an error on this line, saying *`myresourceitem` resource not found*?:

```
bnd.Source = Application.Current.FindResource("myresourceitem")
```

It is also possible that you are trying to access the `Resource` before you have added it in the `Loaded` event handler... are you trying to access it in a constructor? I have tested your code using a simple `string` as the `myresourceitem` value and it works just fine.

---

UPDATE >>>

In order to set a `DynamicResource` programmatically, you need to use the [`FrameworkElement.SetResourceReference` method:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.setresourcereference.aspx)

```
// To change the value:
Application.Current.Resources["myresourceitem"] = "Some new value";
// To set the value
tb.SetResourceReference(TextBlock.TextProperty, "myresourceitem");
```

Note that you could just as easily change the above value after setting the `DynamicResource`... because it's dynamic.

Comment: 'myresourceeitem' is recognized because the dynamic textblock shows the proper text of 'myresourceitem' on the screen. But when - during the course of the program - i change the contents of 'myresourceitem' - the textblock text does not change. Could you show we me how i can set the textblock.text property ot a dynamic Resource?

Comment: @HenriettevandeHaar ah there you go; "during the course of the program - i change the contents of 'myresourceitem'".. Is this a string? Won't work, you are going to need something that implements INotifyPropertyChanged or a DO when doing changes like this from the code.

Comment: I would agree with @Stian. In order for correct property change mechanisms to work, you should implement a data bindable property instead of your `Resource`, even if you still initialise the property from the `Resource`.

Comment: Actually 2 resourcedictionaries dict1 and dict2 are created. dict1 and dict2 are identical, they have the same resourcekeys. The only difference is the language of the strings they contain. As response to a click on a menu item these dictionaries are exchanged: application.current.Resources=dict2 oder dict1. This works fine with the textblocks in XAML-Code containing Text="{DynamicResource myresourceitem}". But not with my dynamic binding. Maybe you can show me how just to assign a dynamic resource to a textblock in behind code. You can answer in c#, I can 'translate' that.

Comment: @Sheridan, tx very much. SetResourceReference did it!